# REGEX get all matched patterns by SQL DB2

Tags: sql, db2

all.
I need to extract from the string by REGEX all that matching the pattern "TTT\d{3}"

For the string in example i would like to get:

```
TTT108,TTT109,TTT111,TTT110
```

The DB2 function i would like to use is `REGEXP_REPLACE(str,'REGEX pattern', ',').`

The number of matching can be 0,1,2,3... in each string.

Thank you.

The example:

```
TTT108(optional);TTT109(optional);TTT111(optional);TTT110optional);ENTITYLIST_2=(optional);ENTITYLIST_3=(optional);Containment_Status=(optional)
```

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the valid instead of replacing the invalid characters, please check if this helps:

```
with data (s) as (values
('TTT108(optional);TTT109(optional);TTT111(optional);TTT110optional);ENTITYLIST_2=(optional);ENTITYLIST_3=(optional);Containment_Status=(optional)')
)
select listagg(sst,', ') within group (order by n)
from (
select n,
       regexp_substr(s,'(TTT[0-9][0-9][0-9])', 1, n)
from   data
cross  join (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) x (n) -- any numbers table
where  n <= regexp_count(s,'(TTT[0-9][0-9][0-9])')
) x (n,sst)
```

Comment: Thank you for response.<br>Each row in the table has its own string.  so i can't use with data (s) as (values
('TTT108(optional);TTT109(optional);TTT111(optional);TTT110optional);ENTITYLIST_2=(optional);ENTITYLIST_3=(optional);Containment_Status=(optional)')
)  because it doesn't constant value

Comment: data is just a substitute. You would use your table instead of data and the column in your table instead of s

Answer (score 1):

For any number of tokens & Db2 versions before 11.1:

```
select id, listagg(tok, ',') str
from 
(
  values 
    (1, 'TTT108(optional);TTT109(optional);TTT111(optional);TTT110optional);ENTITYLIST_2=(optional);ENTITYLIST_3=(optional);Containment_Status=(optional)')
) mytable (id, str)
, xmltable
(
'for $id in tokenize($s, ";") let $new := replace($id, "(TTT\d{3}).*", "$1") where matches($id, "(TTT\d{3}).*") return <i>{string($new)}</i>' 
passing mytable.str as "s"
columns tok varchar(6) path '.'
) t
group by id;
```